# Manga where NEET is forced to go to high school to gather information about girl

Tags: doubt-amano

Here's what I remember (sorry if it's not helping much) :

It's about a NEET who is forced to go to high school by his father to gather some information about some high school girl (I think the girl is probably his father's illegitimate child)

- The male MC really likes lollipops, has black typical hair (not long)
- It's said in the manga that it's easy for MC to win over a person's heart
- His father is a doctor (?), wears glasses, has long white hair (ponytail)
- His mother is an owner of a men's club, wears a kimono and has some connection with the police

The the first girl has a part time job at a cafe.

I remember of some scenes where:

- The MC wraps himself in a blanket, and then his father came.
- The girl gives the MC some bento, the MC gives the bento back along with a lollipop.
- MC helps the first girl cleaning the dish in the cafe.
- MC talks with some fat guy in a hat (which is stalking the first girl) in a cave
- At the end, there's a scene where the manager of the cafe is arrested by police (along with the fat guy) with the help of the MC's mother (wearing a kimono)

Comment: Could it be [Nakaimo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakaimo_-_My_Sister_Is_Among_Them!)?

Comment: sorry guys, i know both and those arent what i meant. thanks anyway. i just read it last month but i deleted my browsing history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [**Doubt!**](http://myanimelist.net/manga/51705/Doubt!) by Sakuya Amano.

<sup>Not to be confused with an entirely different series [Doubt](http://myanimelist.net/manga/5293/Doubt) by Yoshiki Tonogai</sup>

#### Synopsis

> Ichiru Kanzaki is given an offer he can't refuse: to clear his entire debt, he has to enroll in the high school where his father works to track down his father's illegitimate daughter, his own younger half-sister, whom he has never met. But which girl is she?

The description in the question matches the events in chapter 1 of the manga.

Below are two pages towards the end of the chapter, showing the main character's mother and her background (owner of a men's club and well-known by the police).

[image]
[image]

Comment: I was meant to refer to this series, but being unable to check the website directly I just copied the link without knowing what it actually leads to. Didn't think there was another series with the same name.

Comment: THANK YOU ! you're a life saver, i've been searching it for a week, looked through nearly 100 page at some manga website. its true at first i thought it was "doubt" which is about a killer wearing bunny mask. again, thank you guys !

Comment: @Tidusyukimura If this answers your question, you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark under the voting buttons.